# How a client behaves if same IP address is assigned to two different interfaces?

Tags: network, dhcp

First of all, these questions are just out of curiosity. I don't have such configuration, I'm just wondering how a box would behave in such environment.

Say we have a Linux box with two network interfaces, each connected to *different* networks with *same* DHCP configuration. And by chance, both DHCP servers of two networks assigned the same IP to this client.

- Would client accept it as it is or request a new IP from the DHCP server in the second network?
- In case it would accept it as it is, (let's say 192.168.1.100) what would happen if I bind a MySQL server to this address?  Which interface would it listen?
- Let's say I'm to ping 192.168.1.103 and this IP exists in both networks. Which one would get pinged?
- If both networks provides Internet connectivity, which one gets preferred and how can we (or can we) manually set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would client accept it as it is or request a new IP from the DHCP
>   server in the second network?

Probably it would accept it and be fine, depends on the dhcp client implementation.

> In case it would accept it as it is, (let's say 192.168.1.100) what
>   would happen if I bind a MySQL server to this address? Which interface
>   would it listen?

Probably MySQL would complain, but then I've never tried it.

> Let's say I'm to ping 192.168.1.103 and this IP exists in both
>   networks. Which one would get pinged?

Maybe both, good question. Why don't you try it and see?

> If both networks provides Internet connectivity, which one gets
>   preferred and how can we (or can we) manually set it?

For this you would want to look at the default route in the routing table of the OS.

These are all questions that will be determined by the software implementation, so it depends on your OS, you could look up the code and see or just try it with a few machines and some network cables.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to try it but I did not wanted to mess with the network configuration in my office,  for it would be a massive pain in my head to turn it to way it was before. And I don't have enough hardware in my home network to put such configuration together. But then again, maybe I can try to build an environment with some virtual machines hooked up together. Thanks again for answers!

Comment: That's a good idea using VMs.